# What should be returned as int& when we don't have a proper lvalue in c++?

Tags: c++

Today,My professor wrote this code in his computer:

```
int& at(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= maxsize){
        cout<<"The index is not valid"<<endl;
        return ;}
    return elements[index];
}
```

I'm 90 percent sure that the code was exactly the same as above.
But when I wrote it in my visual studio 2015 I got error.
The compiler wanted me to return an int& in the first return statement.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Well of course the first return can't be empty ... What do you expect?

Comment: It is an array.But I think the problem is with the first return statement

Comment: Was the statement maybe `return{};`?

Comment: The console output doesn't change anything.

Comment: @deviantfan I edited the question,take another look at it

Comment: I just did, and my reaction is two comments above.

Comment: @Rakete1111 No,I tried it.no change

Comment: @Rakete1111 What do you mean by" 
The console output doesn't change anything" I'm not doing anything by console output but cout ?

Comment: Anyways, what you *should* do is to throw an exception. No return of any kind (in the error branch)

Comment: @MohammadGhanatian `What do you mean by" The console output doesn't change anything"? ` I mean that the `cout` does not make a difference. The problem is the return and nothing else.

Comment: @deviantfan Yeah I know.But I want This structure.to print an error not exception handling

Comment: @deviantfan yeah,but how can I fix it this way?

Comment: `I'm not doing anything by console output but cout ?` Usually cout is a form of console output. `yeah,but how can I fix it this way?` I just told you. There is no "error value for lvalue references" you could return.

Comment: It looks like your professor does not know C++.

Comment: You know what,Give me some code

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I respect him.he has a phd in AI maybe "I" can not remember what he said or you don't know the correct answer

Comment: `You know what,Give me some code` VTC now. Because `There is no "error value for lvalue references" you could return.` and you're just lazy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has no interest in solving the problem

Comment: He might certainly be a PhD in AI. But that doesn't mean that he knows C++.

Comment: @MohammadGhanatian well if the function is declared as returning a reference to an int then it always has to return a reference to int since that is the contract. a `return;` will not do.

Comment: @deviantfan I asked a question respectfully.

Comment: @MohammadGhanatian Yes, but after 20-30 comments you just don't want to understand that your professor doesn't know anything about C++ (or you just misremembered what he wrote), and you reject the proper solution because the professor has to be right (he isn't)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik THE CODE COMPILED PERFECTLY IN THE CLASS

Comment: ...and shouting is not respectful anymore, and no this does not compile. We told you what to do, it's up to you now.

Comment: @deviantfan But you didn't give me a correct answer,You just wrote the compiler error and wrote that to me ,something I did for almost 20 times today

Comment: @MohammadGhanatian Wrong. Read again.

Comment: @deviantfan You gotta be an ethics guy not a good coder.

Comment: ...Bye, I'm done here. If you want to engage in stupid discussions, become a politician. It's fine for me if you don't want to know better than your professor, but don't blame us for it.

Comment: Because the "code compiled perfectly" doesn't mean that it's right. Just look around on stackoverflow.com. Plenty of examples of code that "compiled perfectly", yet turned out to be utterly broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
int global_incorrect_value = 42;

int& at(int index) 
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= maxsize)
    {
        cout<<"The index is not valid"<<endl;
        return global_incorrect_value;
    }
    return elements[index];
}
```

Or this:

```
std::optional<int*> at(int index)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= maxsize)
        return {};
    else
        return &elements[x];
}
```

Or that:

```
int* at(int index)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= maxsize)
        return nullptr;
    else
        return &elements[x];
}
```

Or even that:

```
int& at(int index)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= maxsize)
        throw std::logic_error;
    else
        return elements[x];
}
```

Or if you are extreme masochist:

```
int& at(int index)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= maxsize)
        explode();
    else
        return elements[x];
}
```

But you cannot do it "like your professor" - posted code is not even close to legal C++.

Comment: My professor did it right,bro.I did remember it in a wrong way.I asked one of my classmates.and she told me that our professor returned elements(0)  in that position.as I said before my professor is an specialist in c++.he is perfect.

Comment: If you see him you will be in love with him.so please don't judge people fast

Comment: And I'm gonna ask my friends before posting in SO in future.

Answer (score -1):

as I understand the code, I think this function get a value from the array called element and return the value if it found so I will explain my answer in this situation 
this is a syntax error you don't return anything to a function that returns a value, not void function and should this function not return any value the answer should be in the memory because you return the reference to that value see the example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int elements[10];
int maxsize = 10;
int notFound = -1; // this a value to know that we are access a value out of range so when return -1 we handle it and we write it as a varible not return -1 to have a refrence in memory to return 
int& at(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= maxsize){
        cout<<"The index is not valid"<<endl;
        return notFound; 
    }
    return elements[index];
}
```

hope this helpful your question is not clear

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> // i use mingw compiler` that's bad nonetheless